# App Service Linux: Error in get or Add Endpoint: pod.fixupIpTables

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I have this error since a few days, someone else happens?, I need some help to recover the app service.

2022-12-17T09:58:05.475Z INFO  -  Status: Downloaded newer image for 10.0.3.138:13209/appsvc/php:8.1-fpm_20221208.1.tuxprod
2022-12-17T09:58:05.479Z INFO  - Pull Image successful, Time taken: 3 Minutes and 7 Seconds
2022-12-17T09:58:05.520Z INFO  - Starting container for site
2022-12-17T09:58:05.520Z INFO  - docker run -d --expose=8080 --name mysite_1_d62e790c -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=mysite -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e PORT=8080 -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=mysite.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=67e61faf16b7de2d5d297e6f2795d58b970924c4839c107793fe67be65ec83bd -e WEBSITE_USE_DIAGNOSTIC_SERVER=False appsvc/php:8.1-fpm_20221208.1.tuxprod

2022-12-17T09:58:05.520Z INFO  - Logging is not enabled for this container.
Please use https://aka.ms/linux-diagnostics to enable logging to see container logs here.
2022-12-17T10:00:35.871Z ERROR - Container create failed for mysite_1_d62e790c with System.Exception, Error in get or Add Endpoint: pod.fixupIpTables error in FixupIPTables: Failed to host iptable rules: Failed to populate the following iptables:
Err on iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j ANTARES : Failed to add the rule for iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j ANTARES:  exit status 2
Err on iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j ANTARES : Failed to add the rule for iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j ANTARES:  exit status 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually created a new app service plan. I migrated my app service to that new app service plan and the problem is gone.